# Number of sudokus with no consecutive arithmetic progression of length 3 in any row or column.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic, arithmetic-combinatorics

How many such Sudokus are there? Any reference to papers, books, articles or any insight into the problem will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried several search engines, scholarly and not, with no results. Maybe there is a  terminology for them I am unaware of.

**EDIT1** Title updated. No AP for any row or column.

**EDIT2** Title updated. Consecutive AP.

Comment: What do you mean "without an arithmetic progression of length $3$? In any position? Three in a row (or would positions $1,3,5$ count)? Diagonally? At the moment the question needs to be made more specific. Counting the number of valid $9 \times 9$ Sudoku grids is not particularly easy, so unless your constraint simplifies the problem, it is likely to be rather difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. It is understood that I mean no three consecutive entries in the grid, in any row or column, is an arithmetic progression.

Comment: The edit helps, but you should probably also edit the text to include the *consecutive* part of the specification.  Searching the OEIS for "permutation arithmetic progression" led to http://oeis.org/A003407 which uses a different definition.

Comment: That sequence is not quite right. You were correct, the **consecutive** part is needed.

Comment: It might be a useful warm-up exercise to compute the corresponding sequence for the number of permutations of $[n]$ with no three consecutive terms in arithmetic progression.  Starting at $n=1$, I get $1,2,4,18$ for the first four terms.

Comment: I have them all for [9], there are 231147.

Comment: @Genomeme, if you've computed them for $[5]$ through $[8]$ as well, you might submit it as a new sequence for OEIS.  I was a little surprised it wasn't already there.  One thing I notice is that $1-(231147/9!)=0.363\approx0.368=1/e$.  I know this is tangential to the question you're asking, but it seems interesting in its own right.

Comment: To return to the sudoku problem, I guess the next warm-up exercise is to count the number of ways to enter the numbers $1$ through $9$ in a $3\times3$ array so that none of its rows or columns constitute a three-term AP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18455/discussion-between-genomeme-and-barry-cipra).

Comment: As of this morning the lower bound on the number of such Sudokus is 82,000,000.

Comment: It looks like really long story with inclusion–exclusion principle, while you consider $3$x$3$ squares as sets of possibilities.

Comment: Yes, it is a long story using that method. I abandoned it very early on. I am approaching it algorithmically using computers. I do not understand your suggestion about $3 \times 3$ squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following C program produces 165K different solutions during a one minute run. This is a literal translation of the Perl code and some C style issues probably remain as I am not an expert C coder. Compiled with GCC 4.8.3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int row, col;
} slot;

typedef slot region[9];

typedef struct {
  region regions[27];
  region *incidence[9][9][3];
} boardinf;

typedef int boardvals[9][9];

void search(boardvals *bvptr, boardinf *binfptr,  int sofar)
{
  int row, col;

  if(sofar == 9*9){
    for(row=0; row<9; row++){
      for(col=0; col<9; col++){
        if(col>0) printf(" ");
        printf("%d", (*bvptr)[row][col]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
  }

  col = sofar % 9; row = (sofar-col) / 9;

  int val;
  for(val = 1; val <= 9; val++){
    (*bvptr)[row][col] = val;

    int admit = 1, regx;
    for(regx=0; regx<3; regx++){
      region *reg = binfptr->incidence[row][col][regx];

      int sx;
      for(sx=0; sx<9; sx++){
        slot *s = (*reg)+sx;

        if(s->row != row || s->col != col){
          if((*bvptr)[s->row][s->col] == val){
            admit = 0;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if(!admit) break;
    }

    if(row>=2){
      int ap[3] = {
        (*bvptr)[row-2][col],
        (*bvptr)[row-1][col],
        (*bvptr)[row][col] };

      if(ap[2]-ap[1] == ap[1]-ap[0]){
        admit = 0;
      }
    }

    if(col>=2){
      int ap[3] = {
        (*bvptr)[row][col-2],
        (*bvptr)[row][col-1],
        (*bvptr)[row][col] };

      if(ap[2]-ap[1] == ap[1]-ap[0]){
        admit = 0;
      }
    }

    if(admit) search(bvptr, binfptr, sofar+1);

    (*bvptr)[row][col] = -1;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  boardinf binf;
  int row, col, regx = 0;

  for(row=0; row<9; row++){
    for(col=0; col<9; col++){
      binf.regions[regx][col].row = row;
      binf.regions[regx][col].col = col;

      binf.incidence[row][col][0] = binf.regions+regx;
    }

    regx++;
  }

  for(col=0; col<9; col++){
    for(row=0; row<9; row++){
      binf.regions[regx][row].row = row;
      binf.regions[regx][row].col = col;

      binf.incidence[row][col][1] = binf.regions+regx;
    }

    regx++;
  }

  int x, y;
  for(y=0; y<3; y++){
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
      int idx = 0;

      for(row=0; row<3; row++){
        for(col=0; col<3; col++){
          binf.regions[regx][idx].row = 3*y+row;
          binf.regions[regx][idx].col = 3*x+col;

          binf.incidence[3*y+row][3*x+col][2] =
            binf.regions+regx;

          idx++;
        }
      }

      regx++;
    }
  }

  boardvals bv;
  for(row=0; row<9; row++){
    for(col=0; col<9; col++){
      bv[row][col] = -1;
    }
  }

  search(&bv, &binf, 0);
}
```

Here are some of solutions that it computed.

```
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 7 9 8 3 6 4 5
6 9 3 5 4 1 2 8 7
5 4 8 2 6 7 9 3 1
7 8 2 6 9 5 4 1 3
4 6 1 7 3 8 5 9 2
9 3 5 4 1 2 7 6 8

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 7 9 8 3 6 4 5
6 9 3 5 4 1 2 8 7
5 4 8 2 6 7 9 3 1
7 8 5 6 9 2 4 1 3
4 6 1 7 3 8 5 9 2
9 3 2 4 1 5 7 6 8

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 7 9 8 3 6 4 5
6 9 3 5 4 1 2 8 7
5 4 8 2 6 7 9 3 1
9 6 2 7 3 5 4 1 8
4 3 5 6 1 8 7 9 2
7 8 1 4 9 2 5 6 3
```

The following three solutions are notable for swapping activity having reached the fourth row.

```
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 4 3 6 8 5 9 1 7
7 8 1 4 9 3 5 6 2
9 6 5 7 1 2 4 3 8
6 3 2 5 4 8 7 9 1
4 9 7 2 3 1 6 8 5
5 1 8 9 6 7 2 4 3

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 4 3 6 8 5 9 1 7
7 8 1 4 9 3 5 6 2
9 6 5 7 1 2 4 3 8
6 3 7 5 4 8 2 9 1
4 1 2 9 3 7 6 8 5
5 9 8 2 6 1 7 4 3

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 4 3 6 8 5 9 1 7
7 8 1 4 9 3 5 6 2
9 6 5 7 1 2 4 3 8
6 3 8 5 4 7 2 9 1
4 9 7 2 3 1 6 8 5
5 1 2 9 6 8 7 4 3
```

Comment: This is a tremendous improvement over my code. It runs like a charm. I would like to request- if I may- that you provide some inline comments that briefly describes some parts of the codes. That way its easier on me to change and move things around without major headaches. I will first optimize on a single core, then optimize it for multiple cores and finally implement it for CUDA GPUs.

Comment: Question: does it double count things? And, is the algorithm exhaustive?

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I will sign off soon for the day. The program does not double count, but obviously there are solutions that are isomorphic under certain permutations and these are counted according to multiplicity.(E.g. consider swapping adjacent rows from the same third of the board.) Theoretically the algorithm is exhaustive but given the number of solutions it probably cannot be used to obtain the total count. For that it clearly needs some sophisticated combinatorics. I gather that was why you posted to MSE in the first place.

Comment: I see. It suffices for me that without any placement of equivalence relations it is exhaustive, I will take care of the "isomorphisms" later on. And, yes you're correct about my posting. Your raw algorithm is substantially faster than mine, after adding some improvement using the dihedral group D4 and some minor improvements it should be in good shape to count everything directly in reasonable time.(Given massive computational hardware) If you have time do add some inline comments to your code.

Answer (score 5):

By way of approaching this problem from a computational perspective here follows a program that will produce these sudokus in the hope that the reader can profit from the algorithmics that are used and perhaps invent a more compact/efficient algorithm. What is used here is backtracking in its most basic form. We sweep the board row by row, placing compatible values that do not contradict any of the constraints (rows/columns/boxes). On the machine where this was tested solutions are produced almost instantly. For more details on the method I recommend the upvoted work by MJD at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906846/).  Here are the first few sudokus with no arithmetic progression of length three:

```
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 6 5 9 1 7 2 8 3
7 9 8 2 6 3 4 1 5
5 3 2 6 9 1 7 4 8
6 8 7 5 4 2 9 3 1
9 4 1 7 3 8 5 6 2

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 6 5 9 1 7 2 8 3
7 9 8 2 6 3 4 1 5
5 3 2 6 9 1 7 4 8
9 4 1 7 3 8 5 6 2
6 8 7 5 4 2 9 3 1

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 6 5 9 1 7 2 8 3
7 9 8 2 6 3 4 1 5
6 8 7 5 4 2 9 3 1
9 4 1 7 3 8 5 6 2
5 3 2 6 9 1 7 4 8
```

Some additional solutions are

```
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 9 7 2 6 1 5 8 3
5 6 8 7 9 3 2 4 1
7 4 2 6 1 8 9 3 5
6 3 5 9 4 2 7 1 8
9 8 1 5 3 7 4 6 2

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 9 7 2 6 1 5 8 3
5 6 8 7 9 3 2 4 1
9 4 1 5 3 2 7 6 8
7 3 5 6 4 8 9 1 2
6 8 2 9 1 7 4 3 5

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 9 7 2 6 1 5 8 3
5 6 8 7 9 3 2 4 1
9 8 1 5 3 7 4 6 2
6 3 5 9 4 2 7 1 8
7 4 2 6 1 8 9 3 5

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 6 9 7
4 9 7 2 6 1 5 8 3
5 6 8 7 9 3 2 4 1
9 8 1 5 3 7 4 6 2
6 4 5 9 1 2 7 3 8
7 3 2 6 4 8 9 1 5
```

The Perl code for this was as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub search {
    my ($board, $regions, $sofar) = @_;

    if($sofar == 9*9){
        for(my $row = 0; $row < 9; $row++){
            for(my $col = 0; $col < 9; $col++){
                print " " if $col > 0;
                print $board->[$row][$col];
            }
            print "\n";
        }
        print "\n";

        return;
    }

    my $col = $sofar % 9; my $row = ($sofar-$col) / 9;

    for(my $val = 1; $val <= 9; $val++){
        $board->[$row][$col] = $val;

        my $admit = 1;
        foreach my $region (@$regions){
            my %seen; my $empty = 0;

            foreach my $slot (@$region){
                my $ent = $board->[$slot->[0]][$slot->[1]];

                if($ent == -1){
                    $empty++;
                }
                else{
                    $seen{$ent} = 1;
                }
            }

            if(scalar(keys(%seen))+$empty != 9){
                $admit = undef;
                last;
            }
        }

        if($row>=2){
            my @ap = (
                $board->[$row-2][$col],
                $board->[$row-1][$col],
                $board->[$row][$col]);
            if($ap[2]-$ap[1] == $ap[1]-$ap[0]){
                $admit = undef;
            }
        }

        if($col>=2){
            my @ap = (
                $board->[$row][$col-2],
                $board->[$row][$col-1],
                $board->[$row][$col]);
            if($ap[2]-$ap[1] == $ap[1]-$ap[0]){
                $admit = undef;
            }
        }


        search($board, $regions, $sofar+1) 
            if defined($admit);

        $board->[$row][$col] = -1;
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $regions = [];

     for(my $line = 0; $line < 9; $line++){
         my $region = [ 
             map {
                 [$line, $_]
             } (0..8) ];
         push @$regions, $region;

         $region = [ 
             map {
                 [$_, $line]
             } (0..8) ];
         push @$regions, $region;
     }

     for(my $row = 0; $row < 3; $row++){
         for(my $col = 0; $col < 3; $col++){
             my $region = [];

             for(my $x = 0; $x < 3; $x++){
                 for(my $y = 0; $y < 3; $y++){
                     push @$region,
                     [$row*3+$x, $col*3+$y];
                 }
             }

             push @$regions, $region;
         }
     }

     my $board =
         [ map { [ (-1) x 9 ] } (0) x 9 ];

     search($board, $regions, 0);
}
```

A sequence from further on in the solution space reads as follows:

```
1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 9 6 7
6 9 7 2 1 3 4 8 5
4 8 5 9 6 7 2 3 1
7 3 2 5 4 1 6 9 8
9 6 1 7 3 8 5 4 2
5 4 8 6 9 2 7 1 3

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 9 6 7
6 9 7 2 1 3 4 8 5
4 8 5 9 6 7 2 3 1
7 3 2 5 9 1 6 4 8
9 6 8 7 4 2 5 1 3
5 4 1 6 3 8 7 9 2

1 2 4 3 5 6 8 7 9
3 5 6 8 7 9 1 2 4
8 7 9 1 2 4 3 5 6
2 1 3 4 8 5 9 6 7
6 9 7 2 1 3 4 8 5
4 8 5 9 6 7 2 3 1
7 3 2 6 9 1 5 4 8
9 6 8 5 4 2 7 1 3
5 4 1 7 3 8 6 9 2
```

**Addendum Sat Nov 15 10:40:01 CET 2014.** By way of responding to the challenge here is an optimized yet simple version of the above that produced 2600 solutions in one minute of computation time, not bad for an interpreted language and ten times as fast as the first version. I suspect if this were to be translated into C the performance would be quite striking.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub search {
    my ($board, $incident, $sofar) = @_;

    if($sofar == 9*9){
        for(my $row = 0; $row < 9; $row++){
            for(my $col = 0; $col < 9; $col++){
                print " " if $col > 0;
                print $board->[$row][$col];
            }
            print "\n";
        }
        print "\n";

        return;
    }

    my $col = $sofar % 9; my $row = ($sofar-$col) / 9;

    for(my $val = 1; $val <= 9; $val++){
        my $key = "$row-$col";
        $board->[$row][$col] = $val;

        my $admit = 1;
        foreach my $region (@{ $incident->{$key} }){
            foreach my $slot (@$region){
                if($slot->[0] != $row || $slot->[1] != $col){
                    my $ent = $board->[$slot->[0]][$slot->[1]];

                    if($ent == $val){
                        $admit = undef;
                        last;
                    }
                }
            }

            last if not defined($admit);
        }

        if($row>=2){
            my @ap = (
                $board->[$row-2][$col],
                $board->[$row-1][$col],
                $board->[$row][$col]);
            if($ap[2]-$ap[1] == $ap[1]-$ap[0]){
                $admit = undef;
            }
        }

        if($col>=2){
            my @ap = (
                $board->[$row][$col-2],
                $board->[$row][$col-1],
                $board->[$row][$col]);
            if($ap[2]-$ap[1] == $ap[1]-$ap[0]){
                $admit = undef;
            }
        }


        search($board, $incident, $sofar+1) 
            if defined($admit);

        $board->[$row][$col] = -1;
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $regions = [];

     for(my $line = 0; $line < 9; $line++){
         my $region = [ 
             map {
                 [$line, $_]
             } (0..8) ];
         push @$regions, $region;

         $region = [ 
             map {
                 [$_, $line]
             } (0..8) ];
         push @$regions, $region;
     }

     for(my $row = 0; $row < 3; $row++){
         for(my $col = 0; $col < 3; $col++){
             my $region = [];

             for(my $x = 0; $x < 3; $x++){
                 for(my $y = 0; $y < 3; $y++){
                     push @$region,
                     [$row*3+$x, $col*3+$y];
                 }
             }

             push @$regions, $region;
         }
     }

     my $incident = {};
     foreach my $region (@$regions){
         foreach my $slot (@$region){
             my $key = join('-', @$slot);
             push @{ $incident->{$key} }, $region;
         }
     }


     my $board = [ map { [ (-1) x 9 ] } (0) x 9 ];

     search($board, $incident, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I do not delve in Perl,( mostly C++, Java and Python) if you could edit your post to briefly describe, in rough terms at least, what your code is doing I would really appreciate it. Yes, these are indeed solutions, in fact the very first few my own code generates. Do you know how efficient your code is? At least empirically? How long did the code take to generate the solutions you found?

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the clarity of the algorithm description. I will check out the link. Your efficiency description however is not useful. My current code just produced 4168 solutions after a minute or so of running on an AMD Quadcore at 2.1Ghz, my lower bound for the number of such sudokus is about 117,000,000 and that took 13 cores @3.7Ghz running for about 50 hours to calculate. I have reasons to believe the count is of magnitude 10^14, so —if I may be pretentious for a moment— I need a bit more than just "solutions were produced almost instantly."

Comment: Let me briefly comment on this. I timed the above Perl script (which runs on any Linux box) and it only produces 200 solutions with 60 seconds running time, so there is definitely room for improvement, for example in not re-checking boxes or rows that have already been verified instead of treating all regions the same. What we have here is a trade-off between brevity, readability, and speed. Maybe what I have above can be simplified while not compromising speed.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time and effort. I will consider this approach after I am done writing the code to implement my current algorithm design. It's a bit long and involved, so it will take me some time.

Comment: In view of your update, I modified my code to tell me the number of solutions when 60 seconds of running time have elapsed. It produced 10393 solutions coming at 60 Seconds and 10459 solutions before it went to 61 seconds.